secure/alternative methods to implement authentication in NextJS
best way to implement authentication(mail and phone) and such functions in NEXTjs not using firebase, which library will you recommended currently sending auth mails through node mailer, there has to be a more secure/efficient way.
using mongoDB, so now way we can use firebase
already used node mailer by setting up an SMTP SERVER. Both paid and free means are welcomed. has to be secure and efficient
